# Send email using Default email provider - SwiftUI

Tags: swift

With the new option of setting the default mail app on settings, I'm wondering if there is a simpler solution to sending emails. Right now I'm using a manual solution adding 3rd party apps manually, like this:

```
...
if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
    self.settingsViewModel.showingFeatureEmail.toggle()
} else if let emailUrl = self.settingsViewModel.createEmailUrl(to: self.generalConstants.email, subject: "Feature request! [\(self.generalConstants.appName)]", body: "Hello, I have this idea ") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(emailUrl)
} else {
    self.settingsViewModel.showMailFeatureAlert = true
}
...

func createEmailUrl(to: String, subject: String, body: String) -> URL? {
    let subjectEncoded = subject.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!
    let bodyEncoded = body.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!

    let gmailUrl = URL(string: "googlegmail://co?to=\(to)&subject=\(subjectEncoded)&body=\(bodyEncoded)")
    let outlookUrl = URL(string: "ms-outlook://compose?to=\(to)&subject=\(subjectEncoded)")
    let yahooMail = URL(string: "ymail://mail/compose?to=\(to)&subject=\(subjectEncoded)&body=\(bodyEncoded)")
    let sparkUrl = URL(string: "readdle-spark://compose?recipient=\(to)&subject=\(subjectEncoded)&body=\(bodyEncoded)")

    if let gmailUrl = gmailUrl, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(gmailUrl) { return gmailUrl }
    else if let outlookUrl = outlookUrl, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(outlookUrl) { return outlookUrl }
    else if let yahooMail = yahooMail, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(yahooMail){ return yahooMail }
    else if let sparkUrl = sparkUrl, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(sparkUrl) { return sparkUrl }
    return nil
}
```

Is there a way to simply ask, what is your default mail app, and open it to write the email?

Using the method above it only checks for apple mail app as default and whatever I have defined for the 3rd parties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### iOS 14.0+ | Swift 5.3

On iOS 14.0; Apple allows iOS users to choose a default mail app in [Settings](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211336#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Settings%20and%20scroll,to%20confirm%20it%27s%20the%20default.)

Users can choose their default email provider in settings, and all you have to do to compose an email would be:

```
let mailTo = "mailto:nemecek@support.com".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) 
let mailtoUrl = URL(string: mailto!)!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(mailtoUrl) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(mailtoUrl, options: [:])
}
```

It needs to be percent-encoded with the `addingPercentEncoding` and then we would create an URL from this and open it with `UIApplication.shared.open`.

We can also use standard URL parameters to customize the `mailto` url. First parameter is denoted with `?` and then others are chained with `&`.

We can add a subject and body like this:

```
let mailTo = "mailto:nemecek@support.com?subject=Cool app feedback&body=Hello I have an issue...".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

Comment: wow that would be incredible and reduce a lot of boilerplate, I'll check it out after work and accept if works as intended. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! Btw., you can also use `openURL` to open the mailto-URL, as referenced here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/openurlaction

Comment: The problem with this one needs to manually return back to the app. It ends up in the Mail app even after cancelling or sending the mail.